# java.io.IOException: Failed to open thrift connection to Cassandra at 127.0.0.1:9160

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

I am facing the below error while calling any method on the  Dataframe like Datafrataframe.show() ..It's happening when I am calling this prom tomcat 7.From test cases it works fime.

Exception Trace:
 attributes : keyspace_name,durable_writes,strategy_class,strategy_options
2015-09-27 17:21:52 [http-apr-8080-exec-2] INFO  c.d.d.c.Cluster - New Cassandra host /127.0.0.1:9042 added
2015-09-27 17:21:52 [http-apr-8080-exec-2] INFO  c.d.s.c.c.CassandraConnector - Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
2015-09-27 17:21:52 [http-apr-8080-exec-2] ERROR c.s.j.s.c.ContainerResponse - The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.io.IOException: Failed to open thrift connection to Cassandra at 127.0.0.1:9160
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.createThriftClient(CassandraConnector.scala:139) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.3.0-M1.jar:1.3.0-M1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.createThriftClient(CassandraConnector.scala:145) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.3.0-M1.jar:1.3.0-M1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withCassandraClientDo(CassandraConnector.scala:151) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.3.0-M1.jar:1.3.0-M1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraRDDPartitioner.partitions(CassandraRDDPartitioner.scala:131) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.3.0-M1.jar:1.3.0-M1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.getPartitions(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:120) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.3.0-M1.jar:1.3.0-M1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]

Additional Trace:
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TFramedTransportFactory.openTransport(Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/apache/thrift/transport/TTransport;
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.createThriftClient(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:41) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.3.0-M1.jar:1.3.0-M1]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.createThriftClient(CassandraConnector.scala:134) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.3.0-M1.jar:1.3.0-M1]
    ... 103 common frames omitted
2015-09-27 17:21:52 [http-apr-8080-exec-2] DEBUG c.p.w.j.WebApplicationWrapper -

Comment: Looks like the wrong version of thrift in tomcat?

Comment: I am using apache-tomcat-7.0.64.How to check thrift on tomcat?